# How to mock method in Mono.flatMap()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I write unit tests for some service and I don't understand , why some method that i mock don't call. I try to test `testDeleteDeviceWhenDeviceNotFound()` method and it's pass, but when I try `testDeleteDeviceSuccess()` I have problems

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DeviceService {

    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;
    private SyncSender syncSender;

    public Mono<Void> deleteDevice(long deviceId) {
        return deviceRepository
                .findById(deviceId)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException()))
                .flatMap(existingDevice -> deviceRepository
                        .delete(existingDevice)
                        .then(syncSender.sendDeviceDelete(existingDevice.getDeviceId()))
                );
    }
```

}
and myTest

```
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DeviceServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;
    @Mock
    private SyncSender syncSender;
    @InjectMocks
    private DeviceService deviceService;

    @Test
@DisplayName("Test deleteDevice when NotFoundException")
void testDeleteDeviceWhenDeviceNotFound() {
    long deviceId = 100L;
    Mockito.when(deviceRepository.findById(deviceId)).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
    Mono<Void> mono = deviceService.deleteDevice(deviceId);
    StepVerifier
            .create(mono)
            .expectErrorMatches(throwable -> throwable instanceof NotFoundException)
            .verify();
}
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test deleteDevice success")
    void testDeleteDeviceSuccess() {
        DeviceModel deviceModel = createDeviceModel();
        deviceModel.setDeviceId(100L);
        Mockito.when(deviceRepository.findById(deviceModel.getDeviceId())).thenReturn(Mono.just(deviceModel));
        Mockito.when(syncSender.sendDeviceDelete(anyLong())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        Mockito.when(deviceRepository.delete(any(DeviceModel.class))).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        deviceService.deleteDevice(deviceModel.getDeviceId());

    }
}
```

Exceptions from junit that one of the stubbed methods were never realized in the code under test, during test execution

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.ecosoft.dms.device.vending.service.DeviceServiceTest.testDeleteDeviceSuccess(DeviceServiceTest.java:172)
  2. -> at com.ecosoft.dms.device.vending.service.DeviceServiceTest.testDeleteDeviceSuccess(DeviceServiceTest.java:173)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

And when I try debug mode I see that I return on  this step.Why?

```
.flatMap(existingDevice -> deviceRepository
```

Comment: How are you injecting your device repository into the service?

Comment: yes, of course, I mock with Mock DeviceRepository deviceRepository, mock testClass with ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class), mock with InjectMocks
DeviceService service. And when I comment mocks syncSender.sendDeviceDelete, deviceRepository.delete test passed.

Comment: Please dont explain how you do it, instead update your question with the relevant code

Comment: Yes, I change it.

Comment: Have you read what the Javadoc says about the subject? The exception itself is telling you where to go for more information. It says right there `More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class`. Search the web for "UnnecessaryStubbingException API" and read the Javadoc for the exception. If after reading and trying you can't figure it out, come back and edit this post with more specific question and details.

Comment: @hfontanez, I know what it exception means. And when I comment mocks syncSender.sendDeviceDelete, deviceRepository.delete test passed. I ask why I return  on step .flatMap(existingDevice -> deviceRepository ?

Comment: @hfontane Unnecessary stubs are stubbed method calls that were never realized during test execution, I don't understand why deviceRepository.delete() don't call  during test execution. I can use Mockito.lenient().when( deviceRepository.delete)  to fix it, but it's not a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your failing test, you have:

```
deviceService.deleteDevice(deviceModel.getDeviceId());
```

This creates a mono, but never launches underlying async tasks.
The test finishes, and Mockito correctly reports that stubbed methods were never called.

You used a StepVerifier in your other test, to my eyes you need to use it here as well to trigger underlying async operations

```
StepVerifier.create(deviceService.deleteDevice(deviceModel.getDeviceId()))
            .verifyComplete();
```

Check simpler examples:

```
@Test
void testMonoNotRun() {
    Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Callable run");
        return 1;
    });
}

@Test
void testMonoRunBySubscribe() {
    Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Callable run");
        return 1;
    }).subscribe();
}

@Test
void testMonoRunByStepVerify() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Callable run");
        return 1;
    })).verifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped a lot. It was solution. It's my first steps to unit tests for async tasks and I make some mistakes.